# Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Can't create directory

Tags: magento2

I have problem with display website:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Can't create directory /home/b2b/domains/style.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/.
```

anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: the issue is with directory ownership and permission of magento folder, secondly instead of creating new question, make all updates in your other question related to permission

Answer (score 1):

for detail, check magento docs that how to setup / fix security issues on magento server
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

however as quick fix you can try below ( on your magento folder ) command and see if it works :

> chown -R www-data:www-data /home/b2b/domains/style.pl/public_html/

Answer (score 0):

Always keep permissions to your var and pub (and generated folder too in case of Magento 2.2) to 777.
To do this simply go to your magento's root and execute following command;

```
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Comment: Unsafe, and not recommended.

Comment: Are you new to magento or something?

Comment: Naveed's answer references a link that includes the proper set of permissions that should be used. Your answer will open a shop up to several vulnerabilities.

Comment: Welp , as far as I can see they are providing read,write and execute permissions to same folders, but to a restricted user group. It's the same thing

Comment: Please see https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Comment: Please clarify and organise your thoughts before commenting any further - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296675/is-chmod-r-ugorwx-safer-than-chmod-r-777

Comment: No idea what that link has to do with running a secure environment, have a good one.